# React.js, adding event listeners in App.js that tie to .jsx pages

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom-events

I am creating an app using react.js and socket.io, I want to add event listeners into my app.js that tie to the html components in my index.jsx file.

Here is my code for App.js

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import io from 'socket.io-client';

import{
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Route,
  Switch,
  Link,
  Redirect
} from "react-router-dom";

//pages
import MainPage from "./pages/index"

const socket = io.connect('http://localhost:4000');

class App extends Component{
  render(){
    return <Router>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" component={MainPage}
    </Router>
  }
}

export default App;
```

here is my code for index.jsx

```js
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

const MainPage = () => {
    return(
        <div>
            <h1>In main page</h1>
            <button id="button">
                SPOMBER
            </button>
        </div>
    );
}

export default MainPage;
```

Normally, you would just reference a piece of the html code by adding and event listener in a <script tag or use a <script src="fileName.js" and adding the event listener to the fileName.js. Is there a way to reference the index.jsx code in the app.js to use event listeners and edit html components based off of data passed between the socket.io server and client? Is there anything similar to this that would work (Pay attention to the few lines above "export default App;")...

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import io from 'socket.io-client';

import{
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Route,
  Switch,
  Link,
  Redirect
} from "react-router-dom";

//pages
import MainPage from "./pages/index"

const socket = io.connect('http://localhost:4000');

class App extends Component{
  render(){
    return <Router>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" component={MainPage}
    </Router>
  }
}

const button = documetn.getelementbyid("button");
button.addeventlistener('click', () => {
console.log("button clicked");
})

export default App;
```

(In the snippet above, the id "button" that is being referenced is the id of the button in index.jsx)
it is crucial that I can create event listeners inside my app.js so that I can use socket.io with the react.js Routes.

Any solution would be greatly appreciated,
Thank you

Comment: In react you attach event handlers directly to the components. [Handling Events](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html) IMO coupling your UI code to your root app container makes your code brittle and less manageable, is an anti-pattern, and using a document query selector to attach an onClick handler will all  be *outside* of react.

Answer (score 0):

In React, to add an event listener to the button you should do something like this in `index.jsx`:

```
    import React, { useCallback } from 'react';
    import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

    const MainPage = () => {
        const handleClick = useCallback((e) =>{
           console.log("button clicked");
        }, []);
        return(
            <div>
                <h1>In main page</h1>
                <button id="button" onClick={handleClick}>
                    SPOMBER
                </button>
            </div>
        );
    }

    export default MainPage;
```

Check here for a more detailed guide:
https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html

Comment: How could I implement sending messages in socket.io to this?

Comment: Check out the following guide: [here](https://medium.com/dailyjs/combining-react-with-socket-io-for-real-time-goodness-d26168429a34).

It should be helpful.